# Android GridView stretch row height

Tags: android, gridview

I have a `GridView` and the items in it are not taking the full height. It would be desired for them to stretch the same way they are doing horizontally. Can i achieve that?

The `GridView` is designed to take the remaining space in a Layout. So its height varies. But it is defined as not scrollable as there is always more than enough space. Is there a solution without manually calculating the height for each item? Or if not can i generically calculate the desired height inside the adapter?

The grid view is defined as follows:

```
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/menu_grid_view"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

I also tried it with `layout_height=0,layout_weight=1` on the items. But it would be a nested weight and it does not work.

Comment: post complete xml file

Comment: See my other comment. The xml is not the problem. The weight on the GridView is working. The items inside the grid are not filling the whole space. And the xml ist just a LinearLayout with a button above and beyond the grid, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this to be done.

weight will work only with linear layout.

you can try this I hope this will help you to understand the issue why you are not getting correct layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:text="textview"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:id="@+id/menu_grid_view"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry but you understood it wrong. The GridView has the correct size. Its items just don't fill the space. So the items need to expand heightwise not the grid itself...